# How to construct an API endpoint with foreign keys replaced by their values?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, api-design, marshmallow

I am currently building an API using Flask, SQLAlchemy and Marshmallow. I have a fairly simple DB model like so:

```
class Transaction(db.Model):
    #Transaction Model
    __tablename__ = 'transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category', uselist=False, lazy='select')
    sub_category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sub_categories.id'))
    sub_category = db.relationship('SubCategory', uselist=False, lazy='select')
    account = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    inner_transfer = db.Column(db.Boolean)



class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    transaction = db.relationship('Transaction')
```

My Marshmallow Schema looks as follows:

```
class CategorySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Category


category_schema = CategorySchema()
categories_schema = CategorySchema(many=True)

class TransactionSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        include_fk = True
```

And a very simple API endpoint:

```
@api.route('/transactions', methods=['GET'])
def transactions():
    all_transactions = Transaction.query.all()
    for transaction in all_transactions:
        transaction.category = Category.query.filter_by(id=transaction.category_id).first()
        print(transaction.category)
    items, errors = transactions_schema.dump(all_transactions)
    return jsonify(items)
```

My problem now: How do I construct a JSON response that has the category name instead of it's primary key in it? I tried the "for transaction in all transactions" bit and in the print statement I get the category name but it doesn't show in my JSON response...

I'm not entirely sure how to write the Database Model. What I'm particularly stuck with is the db.relationship. Declaring it in my Transaction class doesn't seem to help since it only shows the primary key of the Category class as well. I read the Flask-SQLAlchemy docs up and down, but I'm clueless.

Any help and pointers are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: did you look at method and function fields in Marshmallow?  http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_fields.html#function-fields

Something like: `category_name = ma.Function(lambda obj: obj.category.category)`

Comment: I tried it out real quick, but it didn't seem to affect my JSON response. Would I have to get rid of the 'model = Category' and define every field myself in order to use the ma.Function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a simple version of your model to show this in action and seeded the db with two test records:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

# DB Models
class Transaction(db.Model):
    #Transaction Model
    __tablename__ = 'transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category', uselist=False, lazy='select')

class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    transaction = db.relationship('Transaction')

# Schema
class TransactionSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        include_fk = True
    # Here is the function, you do not not need to define all fields you want to dump
    category_name = ma.Function(lambda obj: obj.category.category)
```

Then calling:
`TransactionSchema(many=True).dump(Transaction.query.all()).data`

Yields:
`[{u'category': 1, u'category_id': 1, u'category_name': u'Test1', u'id': 1},
 {u'category': 2, u'category_id': 2, u'category_name': u'Test2', u'id': 2}]`

Could also just overwrite your field with the funtion and make it dump only:

```
class TransactionSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    include_fk = True
category = ma.Function(lambda obj: obj.category.category, dump_only=True)
```

Yields:
`[{u'category': u'Test1', u'category_id': 1, u'id': 1},
 {u'category': u'Test2', u'category_id': 2, u'id': 2}]`

Comment: You are my HERO! Thank you very much! It didn't work before when I tried it out because I put the ma.Function under the Meta class instead of directly under the Schema class.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether this an "Ok-Thing" to do though? This way seems pretty easy (once you know it) so I'm glad. There's no way to get category name from the categories table via the "db.relationship" function right?!

Comment: I think its fine.  You might be able to create another field in your model __init__.  Another option could be to return the category as a nested field in your marshalled data, but that would could have a performance impact, so I think this is a good option if all you need is the name.

Comment: category = ma.Nested(CategorySchema])

Comment: By another field in my model init you mean something like "translating the category primary key to it's corresponding value" in the init?

Yeah I really only need the name (if I were to make a query with pure SQL I'd left join the categories table on the transactions table)

Comment: "translating the category primary key to it's corresponding value" in the init?"  yup